# BrowserSync - Input of type URL removing the protocol from the string

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, browser-sync

I'm working with a template of nunjucks and there's a input of text type that is receiving a url from the server.

The problem is that the input is removing the protocol from the string in it's value attribute. 
Seeing the logs, the string is being passed correctly to the template.

That's the string passed as the value attribute to the input: `http://localhost:8080/uploads/1587335326160-desafio-07-chef-edição.png`

That's the input behavior, as i said before, it's removing the protocol: 
[image]

And the code:

```
 {% if chef.avatar_url %}
    <input name="avatar_url" type="url" id="avatar_url" class="field" disabled title="Link do seu avatar" value="{{chef.avatar_url}}"/>
{% endif %}
```

Is the problem related to the input?

Comment: There are certain times when browsers will either accept urls without protocol or even truncate urls with protocols and in the background automatically determine whether to use `http://` or `https://`.  It should be OK. If you don't want that behavior, change `type='url'` to `type='text'`

Comment: *"there's a input of file type"*. Your code shows an input with `type="url"`. Which one is it `"file"` or `"url"`?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it actually is a text input

Comment: it's removing the protocol with the text type and also the url type

Comment: I think that it's something related with URI Encoding

Comment: That definitely has nothing to do with the input. I just tried it in a playground and it works. I can't share as it doesn't generate a url but are you 100% sure it's not happening before? check what chef.avatar_url is before it reaches the input value

Comment: try type text, and inspect the element in the browser, be sure that the type is changed

Comment: i'm trying with a hard coded value like "http://localhost:8080/uploads/1588522304409-burger.png"

Comment: lol the link that i sent to you is not showing the protocol either

Comment: It seems to be something related with browser-sync

Comment: @LauraBeatris can you display the avatar_url in a `<p>` tag to see if it has the expected format ? This way we know if it's because of the `input`

Comment: @MickaelB. I figured out that the problem is related with BrowserSync lib. When i run the server with nodemon, the url appear normally.

Comment: @LauraBeatris It has nothing to with the browser, if you paste a link here in the comments SO will remove the protocol, since it doesn't add any additional info. Linking to an website is the default case and are 99.99% of all urls here on SO. If you want to display it with protocol surround it with \` tags to mark it as code. `https://www.example.com` I would suggest you first follow Arber Sylejmani's suggestion and check if `chef.avatar_url` contains the protocol. I have the feeling it doesn't.